# Recreate @Component based on changes in database in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a component that reads values from database and returns some object. User have access to change the values in database. I have to recreate the object as soon as some changes are reflected in database. As the object depends on database. I don't know even it is possible, So just to be sure if there is a way or not. Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you fetching the data from the database each time you call your Component?  Then your component would be up2date constantly. Another approach would be to implement a Cache (I suggest Caffeine Cache) and everytime a user updates an object in the database just call the Component to reset the cache and fetch the data when it is called again. 
Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @MarkusG. I think the OP wants to update the POJO object, based on any schema changes on the database object

Comment: @noobCoder yes that is exactly my problem. I don't want to fetch data every time. Just when there are some changes.

Comment: @BHAVUKGARG, wait that's different. I thought you were saying your object schema changed, but you basically want to get updates if anything changes in your DB object instead of querying and checking every time?

Comment: As Components are created initially in Application Context, I think there should be some event handling kind of thing to monitor database and recreate the component again.

Answer (score 1):

As per the OP's comment, he is looking to get updates when his database object changes.

Essentially, what you are looking for is Change Data Capture (CDC). I'm not sure what database you are working with but you can take a look at [Debezium](https://debezium.io/). It is an open-source distributed platform for change data capture. Start it up, point it at your databases, and your apps can start responding to all of the inserts, updates, and deletes that other apps commit to your databases.